# Comparing existing DB schema and manually updating schema using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, database-schema

What are the options available for comparing existing DB schema and with the schema that can be constructed from the mapping files in Hibernate.
I would like to do the comparison manually and run a DB schema update script if there are differences.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [schemacrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/) for this.  Using schemacrawler, you could dump each schema into a file and then use a file compare tool to find the deltas between the two schemas.